# Validate dynamic Form Field in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, bootstrap-4, dynamic-forms

I have a problem validating dynamic form fields (can be added or reduced), I try to use the [following library](https://andyhu92.github.io/react-bootstrap4-form-validation/#/) (**React Bootstrap4 Form Validation**) for validation, but the error message always appears: *Uncaught TypeError: firstErrorInput is undefined* in the console, can anyone help me, or provide another alternative to create dynamic form fields and how to do the validation? The link image below is an example of the result I want. Thank you in advance.

[Example of the result I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTLKp.png)

**Here is my code:**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { ValidationForm, TextInput } from 'react-bootstrap4-form-validation';

function ModalProductSpec () {
    const [inputList, setInputList] = useState([{ product_specTitle: "", product_specDescription: "" }]);
    const [loader, setLoader] = useState(false);
    const formRefs = useRef();

    const handleInputChange = (e, index) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        const list = [...inputList];
        list[index][name] = value;
        setInputList(list);
    };

    const handleAddClick = () => {
        setInputList([...inputList, { product_specTitle: "", product_specDescription: "" }]);
    };

    const handleRemoveClick = index => {
        const list = [...inputList];
        list.splice(index, 1);
        setInputList(list);
    };

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setLoader(true);
        console.log(inputList);
    }

    return (
        <div className="modal fade" id="modal-product-add-spec" tabIndex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div className="modal-dialog modal-xl" role="document">
            <div className="modal-content">
                <div className="modal-header bg-danger">
                    <h5 className="modal-title">Add Specification Product</h5>
                    <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <ValidationForm onSubmit={handleSubmit} ref={formRefs}>
                    <div className="modal-body">
                        {
                            inputList.map(( field, index ) => {
                                return (
                                <div key={index}>
                                    <div className="row form-group mb-1" >
                                        <div className="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2">Spec Title :</div>
                                        <div className="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
                                            <TextInput type="text" className="form-control" name="product_specTitle" autoComplete="off" 
                                            value={field.product_specTitle} onChange={e => handleInputChange(e, index)} required/>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2">Spec Description :</div>
                                        <div className="col-lg-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5">
                                            <TextInput type="text" className="form-control" name="product_specDescription" autoComplete="off" 
                                            value={field.product_specDescription} onChange={e => handleInputChange(e, index)} multiline rows="5" required/>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="col-lg-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 align-self-center">
                                        {inputList.length !== 1 && <button className="btn btn-danger btn-sm mr-1 mt-1 mt-md-0" onClick={() => handleRemoveClick(index)}><i className="fa fa-minus"></i></button>}
                                        {inputList.length - 1 === index && <button className="btn btn-primary btn-sm mt-1 mt-md-0" onClick={handleAddClick}><i className="fa fa-plus"></i></button>}
                                        </div>
                                    </div> <hr />
                                </div>
                                )
                            })
                        }


                    </div>
                    <div className="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-danger">
                            {!loader ? ('Save') : (<span className="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>) }
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </ValidationForm>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
    )
}

export default ModalProductSpec;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

```
yarn add react-hook-form
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-usefieldarray-ssugn

https://react-hook-form.com/api/usefieldarray